# ColdFusion 8 - Application.cfc interference

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-8, application.cfc, cfimport

I've just had a strange issue with a client's website, my live domain was using my development domains Application settings. I've not had this issue before, and removing `cflock` around the `Application.dsn` (amongst other settings) resolved the issue.

As mentioned I have a live site `*www.*` and development site `*dev.*`, my development site is in a subfolder of the live site `/dev/` and has it's own `Application.cfc`.

My first question is, if I have variables in my Application scope in the dev folder will this overwrite the Application scope variables in the folder above? Will it consider it the same scope? If so, then this might explain what the issue and if not then I am stumped.

My second question is, how should I correct `cflock` application scope variables in my application.cfc? Should I be doing this at all?

Here is my Application.cfc, advice would be greatly appreciated:

```
<cfcomponent output="true">

<cfimport taglib="taglib" prefix="func">

<!---

        Check staging directory exists

--->

<cfset THIS.env = "staging">

<!---

        Set application vars

--->

<cfset THIS.applicationTimeout = createTimeSpan(0,0,0,0)>
<cfset THIS.sessionManagement="Yes">
<cfset THIS.clientManagement = true>
<cfset THIS.clientStorage = "cookie">
<cfset THIS.loginStorage = "cookie">
<cfset THIS.setDomainCookies = false>
<cfset THIS.setClientCookies = true>
<cfset THIS.scriptProtect = true>
<cfset THIS.secureJSON = true> <!--- Added 12.06.13 --->

<!---

        Check environment
        Set application name

--->

<cfif THIS.env EQ "staging">
    <cfset THIS.applicationName = "devenv">
    <cfset THIS.dsn = "devenv">
<cfelse>
    <cfset THIS.applicationName = "liveenv">
    <cfset THIS.dsn = "liveenv">
</cfif>

<cfif #cgi.HTTP_HOST# NEQ "localhost">
    <cfset THIS.dirpath = "http://#cgi.http_host#">
    <cfset THIS.componentPath = "cfcs.">
<cfelse>
    <cfset urlString = #mid(cgi.PATH_INFO, 2, 200)#>
    <cfset THIS.localhostFolderName = #spanexcluding(urlString, "/")#>
    <cfset THIS.dirpath = "http://localhost/#THIS.localhostFolderName#">
    <cfset THIS.componentPath = "#THIS.localhostFolderName#.cfcs.">
</cfif>
<cfset THIS.name = THIS.applicationName>
<cfset THIS.sessiontimeout = createtimespan(0,0,20,0)>
<cfset THIS.setClientCookies = true>
<cfset THIS.visitor = true>


<cffunction name="onApplicationStart" returntype="void">

    <cfset APPLICATION.name = THIS.applicationName>
    <cfset APPLICATION.dsn = THIS.dsn>
    <cfset APPLICATION.DSN = THIS.dsn>
    <cfset APPLICATION.dirpath = THIS.dirpath>
    <cfset APPLICATION.componentPath = THIS.componentPath>
    <cfif #cgi.HTTP_HOST# EQ "localhost">
        <cfset APPLICATION.localhostFolderName = THIS.localhostFolderName>
    </cfif>

    <!--- USED FOR PATHS AND URLS --->  

    <!--- Property image upload paths ---->
    <cfset APPLICATION.paths = StructNew()>

    <!---

            Check environment
            Set local root

    --->

    <cfif THIS.env EQ "staging">

        <cfset APPLICATION.paths.localRoot = "c:\websites\foobar.co.uk\dev\">

    <cfelse>

        <cfset APPLICATION.paths.localRoot = "c:\websites\foobar.co.uk\">

    </cfif>


    <cfset APPLICATION.paths.logs = APPLICATION.paths.localRoot & "logs\">
    <cfset APPLICATION.paths.logFile = APPLICATION.paths.logs & "site_log.txt">       
    <cfset APPLICATION.paths.property = StructNew()>
    <cfset APPLICATION.paths.property.image = APPLICATION.paths.localRoot & "images\property\">
    <cfset APPLICATION.paths.property.large = APPLICATION.paths.property.image & "large\">
    <cfset APPLICATION.paths.property.thumb = APPLICATION.paths.property.image & "thumbs\">
    <cfset APPLICATION.paths.property.cmsThumb = APPLICATION.paths.property.image & "thumbs\cms\">
    <cfset APPLICATION.paths.property.pdf = APPLICATION.paths.localRoot & "pdf\">
    <cfset APPLICATION.paths.property.pdfGenerated = APPLICATION.paths.property.pdf & "generated\">
    <cfset APPLICATION.newsUploadPath = APPLICATION.paths.localRoot & "images\news\">
    <cfset APPLICATION.articlesUploadPath = APPLICATION.paths.localRoot & "images\articles\">

    <cfset APPLICATION.articlesThumbsDir = "../images/articles/thumbs/">
    <cfset APPLICATION.articlesContentDir = "../images/articles/assets/">
    <cfset APPLICATION.articlesAssetsDir = "../articles/assets/">

    <!--- Site URLS ---->
    <cfset APPLICATION.urls = StructNew()>
    <cfset APPLICATION.urls.root = "http://" & CGI.server_name & "/">
    <cfset APPLICATION.urls.com = "com">
    <cfset APPLICATION.urls.tagLib = APPLICATION.urls.root & "taglib/">
    <cfset APPLICATION.urls.cms.tagLib = "http://" & CGI.server_name & ":" & CGI.server_port & "/admin/tagLib/">
    <cfset APPLICATION.RowsPerPage = 10>

    <!--- Property URLS --->
    <cfset APPLICATION.urls.property.pdf = APPLICATION.urls.root & "pdf/">
    <cfset APPLICATION.urls.property.image = APPLICATION.urls.root & "images/property/">
    <cfset APPLICATION.urls.property.large = APPLICATION.urls.root & "images/property/large/">
    <cfset APPLICATION.urls.property.thumb = APPLICATION.urls.root & "images/property/thumbs/">
    <cfset APPLICATION.urls.property.cmsThumb = APPLICATION.urls.root & "images/property/thumbs/cms/">
    <cfset APPLICATION.urls.news.image = APPLICATION.urls.root & "images/news/">
    <cfset APPLICATION.urls.articles.image = APPLICATION.urls.root & "images/articles/">

    <cflock scope="Application" timeout="5" type="Exclusive">

        <cfscript>

            /* Commonly used objects and queries */

            // DAOs 
            APPLICATION.propertyDAO = CreateObject("component", "cfcs.dataobjects.propertyDAO").init(APPLICATION.dsn);

            APPLICATION.propertyImageDAO = CreateObject("component", "cfcs.dataobjects.property_imageDAO").init(APPLICATION.dsn);
            APPLICATION.propertyToPropertyImageDAO = CreateObject("component", "cfcs.dataobjects.property_to_property_imageDAO").init(APPLICATION.dsn);
            APPLICATION.propertyToPropertyLocationDAO = CreateObject("component", "cfcs.dataobjects.property_to_property_locationDAO").init(APPLICATION.dsn);
            APPLICATION.propertyToPropertyTypeDAO = CreateObject("component", "cfcs.dataobjects.property_to_property_typeDAO").init(APPLICATION.dsn);
            APPLICATION.propertyToPropertyTenureDAO = CreateObject("component", "cfcs.dataobjects.property_to_property_tenureDAO").init(APPLICATION.dsn);     
            APPLICATION.propertyGroupDAO = CreateObject("component", "cfcs.dataobjects.property_groupDAO").init(APPLICATION.dsn);     

            // Gateways
            APPLICATION.propertyGateway = CreateObject("component", "cfcs.dataobjects.propertyGateway").init(APPLICATION.dsn);
            APPLICATION.propertyImageGateway = CreateObject("component", "cfcs.dataobjects.property_imageGateway").init(APPLICATION.dsn); 
            APPLICATION.propertyToPropertyImageGateway = CreateObject("component", "cfcs.dataobjects.property_to_property_imageGateway").init(APPLICATION.dsn);
            APPLICATION.propertyLocationGateway = CreateObject("component", "cfcs.dataobjects.property_locationGateway").init(APPLICATION.dsn);
            APPLICATION.propertyImageGateway = CreateObject("component", "cfcs.dataobjects.property_imageGateway").init(APPLICATION.dsn);
            APPLICATION.propertyTypeGateway = CreateObject("component", "cfcs.dataobjects.property_typeGateway").init(APPLICATION.dsn);
            APPLICATION.propertyToPropertyTypeGateway = CreateObject("component", "cfcs.dataobjects.property_typeGateway").init(APPLICATION.dsn);
            APPLICATION.propertyTenureGateway = CreateObject("component", "cfcs.dataobjects.property_tenureGateway").init(APPLICATION.dsn);
            APPLICATION.propertyToPropertyTenureGateway = CreateObject("component", "cfcs.dataobjects.property_to_property_tenureGateway").init(APPLICATION.dsn);
            APPLICATION.partnerGateway = CreateObject("component", "cfcs.dataobjects.partnerGateway").init(APPLICATION.dsn);

            // Business Objects
            APPLICATION.propertyBO = CreateObject("component", "cfcs.businessobjects.propertyBO").init(APPLICATION.dsn);

            // Common queries
            APPLICATION.qPartners = APPLICATION.partnerGateway.getAllRecords();    
            APPLICATION.qPropertyTypes = APPLICATION.propertyTypeGateway.getAllRecords(); 
            APPLICATION.qPropertyTenures = APPLICATION.propertyTenureGateway.getAllRecords(); 
            APPLICATION.qPropertyMinMaxSize = APPLICATION.propertyGateway.getMinMaxSize();
            APPLICATION.qPropertyLocations = APPLICATION.propertyLocationGateway.getAllRecords();

        </cfscript>
    </cflock>
</cffunction>
<cffunction name="onSessionStart" returntype="void">
    <cflock scope="Session" timeout="5" type="Exclusive">       
        <cfscript>
            SESSION.propertySearchCriteria = CreateObject("component", "cfcs.beans.property_search_criteria").init();
            SESSION.propertySearch = CreateObject("component", "cfcs.beans.property_search").init(SESSION.propertySearchCriteria);
        </cfscript>    
    </cflock>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Could they have been using the same application name? If the application name is the same then they will use the same scope. With different names they should not.

Comment: It is possible that when I was setting up the live / dev env variable test that they temporarily shared the same application name. That would certainly explain the issue. What's the best to setup a live / dev test in the Application.cfc?

Comment: As long as they have different application names then they will be treated as entirely separate applications. So I think your logic is okay. As far as locking that block of code, I think that is okay too. I do the same in my applications.

Comment: I do too, but technically you do not have to lock application variables inside `OnApplicationStart`, unless you intend to invoke that method manually. When *CF* invokes it, the application scope is locked automatically. However, if you manually invoke `OnApplicationStart`, CF does not lock the application scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you change your application name based on the environment it's in? That makes no sense. The application is still the same app, irrespective of whether it's in prod, or you're staging it, or developing it.

Equally, same with the source code. You've got your dev site within your live website? How does this make any sense?

I dunno what's going on with your application variables, but they're bound to the application name (`this.name`), not where the `Application.cfc` is in the directory structure.

I suspect your zero `applicationTimeout` is not helping matters much here. This basically means your application never actually persists... it'll be timing out every request. This makes no sense either.

You do not need to `<cflock>` that code in `onApplicationStart()`. ColdFusion will only allow one request to run `onApplicationStart()`: all other requests will be queued until it's completed, by which time the application has started, so the queued requests won't even attempt to run it.

I think your problem is most likely causes by your poor application framework design, and this weird thing you're doing having dev and prod in the same source code tree (which defies all logic).

Sort your source code out, and the problem won't arise.

Comment: *ColdFusion will only allow one request to run onApplicationStart()* (Not really the main issue here, but ..) my understanding is that is only true when it is invoked automatically in the normal course of application start up. If you invoke it manually, such as to do a reset, it is not single threaded automatically.

Comment: Indeed. And "here's one I made earlier" as it were: http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2012/07/onapplicationstart-is-not-intrinsically.html. I did not want to confuse matters any more than necessary by throwing that in above.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @AdamCameron - In response to your questions, I changed the application name based on the environment it is in so that I can easily swap between live and development and don't have to keep two Application.cfc files, clear it's a bad idea now so will go back to having two App.cfcs. dev is in the same folder tree because of hosting restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional logic to set your application name.

```
if ( YouAreHappy and YouKnowIt ) {
This.name = "ClapYourHands";
}
else {
This.name = "StompYourFeet"; 
}
```

In real life, your if condition would be something that differented the live and test environments.  cgi.http_host is a good candidate.